# Unexpected identifier 'h'. Expected ';' after variable declaration

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I've been reading other posts of similar errors, but the problem always seem to be not so obvious from the error message. Not sure how to approach this.
I've searched my entire project for the letter "h" to see if I can find one that is out of place but nothing comes up.
I've went through all my project files but nothing seems out of order.
I'm using TS and nothing seems to suggest a typo error.

Is there a way I can get more information on this error? Th title is all that I am getting.

EDIT: This is the entire repo https://github.com/Tsabary/deliveroo-clone

Not placing any code because I actually have no idea where this is coming from.

EDIT 2: I didn't touch my code at all, but clicked the reload on my android emulator, and now instead of the previous message, it says `Unexpected identifier 'get'. Expected a parameter list for getter definition.`

Comment: It is very difficult to help without a [mre].

Comment: I've added the link to the entire repo. It's at the very beginning of the project so not many files. I'd post less but no idea to which part of the app this is related to.

Comment: what is the typescript version you are using?

Comment: @VinodA on my machine it is `3.9.5`. I've just ran `npm i typescript@latest` and it remained the same. On the project, which installed TypeScript automatically after suggesting it's a missing dependency and prompted me to install it, I have version `4.9.5`

Comment: `h` looks like an artifact of the JSX transform. Try importing React in your components: `import React from "react";`

Comment: @Kalabasa appreciate your answer. I was able to get rid of the error by re-installing all my node_models. I guess the error was somewhere there. Really non-informative error message.

Answer (score 0):

I need to move the project to a different location so prior to that I've deleted my `package-lock.json` and my `node_modules`, moved the project and reinstalled them. Everything seemed to be installing just fine so didn't even think of it as the issue.

I've again deleted everything and reinstalled, and now everything works, so I guess the error was somewhere in a faulty module installation.